# Symfony - What is the concern of creating modules as bundles?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-bundle

Symfony official documentation says:

> "Don't Create any Bundle to Organize your Application Logic"

https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html

And:

> In Symfony versions prior to 4.0, it was recommended to organize your
> own application code using bundles. This is no longer recommended and
> bundles should only be used to share code and features between
> multiple applications.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html

Lets assume that I have 10 modules in my app: "**Company Module**", "**User Module**", "**Accounting Module**", etc.

Bundles(Modules) are not separate Composer packages; instead, they are committed as part of the app code, and each Bundle(Module) is included in config/bundles.php.

Each module is created as a bundle with its own configuration, and the average size of each configuration is around 100 lines.

For example each of this file have in average 100 lines of code:

```
Module\[MODULE_NAME]\Resource\config\services.yaml
```

Also some of the modules(bundles) have routes config:

```
Module\[MODULE_NAME]\Resource\config\routes.yaml
```

Some of them workflow config:

```
Module\[MODULE_NAME]\Resource\config\workflow.yaml
```

etc.

And that is perfectly fine by me. I want to put module configuration inside each module folder, not in config folder in the root (**config/services.yaml**).

What is alternative? Put everything from each module configuration.yaml to **config/services.yaml** and have messy file with 1000 lines of configuration?

Or put configuration inside each module (which is not bundle) and then import it with inside **config/services.yaml** with:

```
imports:
    - { resource: Module\[MODULE_NAME]\Resource\config\services.yaml }
    - { resource: Module\[MODULE_NAME2]\Resource\config\services.yaml }
    - { resource: Module\[MODULE_NAME3]\Resource\config\services.yaml }
    ...
```

That is also a little bit messy for me.

When I need to use templates within a module that isn't a bundle, I have to place the templates inside a 'templates' folder at the root.

```
templates/MODULE_NAME
templates/MODULE_NAME2
templates/MODULE_NAME3
...
```

This is already the third instance where I repeatedly find myself creating ten folders for each module. There are additional situations, such as translations, where this approach should also be applied, potentially leading to more than 10 instances where this task needs to be performed in the same manner.

Isn't it easier to create a module as a bundle and keep all its components inside that bundle, rather than creating ten folders for each bundle in multiple locations?

I am perfectly happy when "UserModule" code is only in folder for "UserModule" not everywhere around.

What is a general concern of creating a modules as bundles?

Comment: I _think_ the decision is around thinking about bundles as "reusable bundles", and everything else is just "your application". Your way isn't wrong, but it is fighting against the "central configuration" that Symfony is going for. Instead of a single routes.yaml file, you can have 11 (the common one and one for each bundle). Once again, not wrong, and if you are the sole contributor and/or you have great documentation, not a problem. But for some/many/most people, the bundle system is overkill if there's no code reuse.

Comment: Ryan Weaver wrote a great blog on this a couple of years ago, and there's some great back and forth in the comments that provide insights from both sides: https://symfonycasts.com/blog/AppBundle

Comment: You can certainly organize by bundles if you want. In practice it proved difficult to have standalone bundles at the app level.  Bundles tended to cross reference each other and it was not always easy to determine where a given piece of functionality belonged.  Using bundles often added extra work without much value. But again try it and see.